# Durandal technique to refresh an existing page [view/viewmodel]

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I've a dashboard page which shows data relevant to a particular user which is shown in the drop-down at the right hand top corner.

When i select a different user the dashboard should be reloaded/refresh with data relevant to that user.

Router does not work since I navigate to the same page it does not reload the page.Another trick would be to create a dummy page & redirect from there back to dashboard,but i'm looking for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad.

Durandal is leveraging KO heavily so i only needed to update the ViewModel & GUI would get autorefreshed. But the dropdown is not a durandal module.So was trying to figure out a way to notify the Durandal module with the change event.

I realized i was also using http://www.jstorage.info/ & it had a callback for pub/sub as well as listener :) , Issue resolved :)